# Orbital plane evolution and planet discovery via transit method

Tags: exoplanet

I'm aware that our solar system is largely/roughly on a single orbital plane, but haven't other star system's orbital planes been scrambled by billions of years of interaction?

If so - how much chance is there that an exoplanetary system's orbital plane is inclined favourably enough to witness the dimming of a transiting planet across its sun?

Comment: This is a fairly standard question. Google helps: www.iiassvietri.it/down/ases_2015/Lectures_notes/Tr_1.pdf

Comment: $P \simeq R/a$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A few questions regarding the transit of planets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28423/a-few-questions-regarding-the-transit-of-planets)  also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-percent-of-planets-are-in-the-position-that-they-could-be-viewed-edge-on-fr?noredirect=1&lq=1